# Как прочитать переменные окружения

Tags: javascript

Разрабатываю extension для хрома. И возник вопрос, можно ли ему передать переменные окружения так, чтобы внутри экстеншена их прочитать?

Comment: process.env.%NAME%?

Comment: @KonstantinFedorov Как передать их при запуске хрома?

Comment: Возможно как-то поможет это? https://fooobar.com/questions/819103/how-to-set-processenv-before-a-browserified-script-is-run